# Core Data - NSFetchRequestResult: count of items in one-to-many relationship from result?

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

Consider a Core Data model with two Entities: TermDictionary and Term. The TermDictionary has a "name" property, and a one-to-many relationship called "terms" which points to a set of Term objects, each of which consists of two properties: "name" and "score".

I've got an NSFetchRequest which I'm using as a data source for a UITableView which displays all of the TermDictionaries in the database. The idea is that the table will, for each cell, display the name of the dictionary, along with a count of the number of terms in that dictionary.

In the following code snippet, `item` contains an NSFetchRequestResult for the `"TermDictionary"` entity:

```
let thisDict = item as! TermDictionary
cell.textLabel?.text = thisDict.name
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(thisDict.terms?.count ?? 0) terms"
```

...The table cells are correctly displaying the names of the Term Dictionaries, however it looks like `thisDict.terms` is always coming up nil, so the number-of-terms label always shows zero.

Do I need do do something special with `item` rather than just casting it to my `TermDictionary` managed object subclass?

Comment: Hey DanM, It seems that this particular TermDictionary item doesn't have terms items. Try to understand why TermDictionary always has terms relationship nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to do anything special.  If `thisDict.terms` prints as nil, it really is nil.  Check your data store.

Comment: I did check -- the Term entities are all in there, but I don't know how to confirm the relationship by looking at the SQLite file...

Comment: Turns out it was a scoping problem; when I ran context.save() after adding the Terms to the TermDictionary, context was nil. D'oh.